# How to remove this sliding app section?

Tags: home-screen, multi-window

A couple of weeks ago a sliding app section appeared on my home-screen. I have no idea how it got there, and no clue on how to disable/remove it. I tried all I could on the homescreen, to no luck.

Using Galaxy S3, Android 4.1.2, everything standard (so no custom launcher).

[image: Screen shot showing sliding app section]

Any ideas on how to remove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's part of Samsung's *multi window* feature, and was added by a system update. To disable it, go to the main **Settings** app. In the **Device** group, click on **Display**. In the **General** group, there's a **Multi window** item. Uncheck this setting to turn off the sliding tray.

If you want to use the multi window feature sometimes, but don't want the sliding tray there all of the time, you can add an item to the *quick setting* menu (at the top of the notification panel). The setting for that is also in **Settings** → **Display**. Click **Notification panel** to go to a page that lets you drag buttons on and off the quick setting menu. **Multi window** is one of the items, and that button toggles the tray on and off.

Comment: As far as I know (I don't own a Samsung device) you can also toggle it on/off (when it's enabled) by holding down the back button (or maybe it is the menu button, not sure).