# How to hide / show the pull out drawer that is pre-loaded on some Samsung devices

Tags: samsung, home-screen-shortcuts, multi-window

Some newer Samsung devices have a pull out tab that stores some of the commonly used applications. I have accidentally enabled and disabled it a number of times, but I don't know how. I don't see anything related to it in device settings or any of the installed apps that would control it.

How do you hide / show this pull out bar?

[image]

<sup>(Click on the image for larger version)</sup>

Comment: What device and Android version? I don't seem to get this when I employ the suggested action, and it seems to be an interesting feature.

Comment: That's part of Samsung's multi window feature; see also: [How to remove this sliding app section?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47202/16575)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable this pull out bar by long pressing the back button.

Comment: What device and Android version? I don't seem to get this when I employ the suggested action, and it seems to be an interesting feature.

Comment: at the current time I am working specifically with a Galaxy Tab 8" (SGH-I467M) with Android 4.1.2. In the past I've seen this same pull out menu thing on other higher end samsung phones/tablets as well, but I don't have a list of all models that I have seen it on.